# Creating a new VTK Project with Visual Studio

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2013, cmake, vtk

I am trying to create a new C++ project that uses VTK in Visual Studio.

I followed the instructions on to how to download, access and build VTK on Windows using CMake and that seemed to go ok. I then tried to create a new project that includes VTK functionality and visualisation but it generates errors where it cannot open any of the VTK header files (it maybe due to the additional dependencies in the project properties but I am not sure what to change or update to make this work).

Does anyone know how to fix this issue? (at the moment I am trying to view a simple cube using the following code):

```
#include <vtkSmartPointer.h>
#include <vtkActor.h>
#include <vtkCubeSource.h>
#include <vtkPolyData.h>
#include <vtkPolyDataMapper.h>
#include <vtkRenderWindow.h>
#include <vtkRenderWindowInteractor.h>
#include <vtkRenderer.h>

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>


int   main(int t) {
if (t==1) {
vtkSmartPointer<vtkCubeSource> cubeSource =
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkCubeSource>::New();

// Create a mapper and actor.
vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper> mapper =
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper>::New();
mapper->SetInputConnection(cubeSource->GetOutputPort());

vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor> actor =
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor>::New();
actor->SetMapper(mapper);

// Create a renderer, render window, and interactor
vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer> renderer =
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer>::New();
vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindow> renderWindow =
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindow>::New();
renderWindow->AddRenderer(renderer);
vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindowInteractor> renderWindowInteractor =
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindowInteractor>::New();
renderWindowInteractor->SetRenderWindow(renderWindow);

// Add the actors to the scene
renderer->AddActor(actor);
renderer->SetBackground(.3, .2, .1);

// Render and interact
renderWindow->Render();
renderWindowInteractor->Start();

        actor->Delete();
        mapper->Delete();
        renderer->Delete();
        renderWindow->Delete();
        renderWindowInteractor->Delete();

    }

  return 0;
 }
```

Also, my CMakeLists file is this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

PROJECT(karman)

find_package(VTK REQUIRED)
include(${VTK_USE_FILE})

add_executable(karman MACOSX_BUNDLE karman)

if(VTK_LIBRARIES)
   target_link_libraries(karman ${VTK_LIBRARIES})
else()
     target_link_libraries(karman vtkHybrid vtkWidgets)
endif()
```

Comment: Can you post the `CMakeLists.txt` you created for your application?

Comment: Ok. Will do. I was having issues with this as well because when  I was trying to configure it I got a   "Could not find a package configuration file provided by "VTK" with any of the following names:  VTKConfig.cmake
vtk-config.cmake"

Comment: In `CMake-gui` when you are configuring your application point the VTK_BIN folder to the build folder you used for vtk.

Comment: I am basing my CMake  off an example I saw online and on a video but just changed the name of the application (http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/IO/SimplePointsReader) so I don't understand why it doesn't work

Comment: I think I have found away around it. Thanks for your help